# Eclipse - Only show tasks for the currently edited file

Tags: eclipse

Is there any way to limit the list of shown tasks in the `Tasks` view? I want to only show tasks contained in the file which I currently edit.

Comment: This question is clear and helpful to me.

Comment: I agree with fossilet ..

Comment: I agree as well. I am puzzled as to why this question is marked in this way.  I have just run into this same problem myself, and the question and answer were both clear and helpful.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try `Configure contents...` in the menu of the `Tasks` view. There you can change the `Scope` to `On selected element only` for example.

Comment: Woks great for TODOs but hides FIXME for some reason...

Comment: @GeorgiGeorgiev: Just create a new configuration where the description should contain the word `FIXME` and select both on the right side.

Comment: To get this to work in Kepler, I had to tick the checkbox on the "TODOs" configuration on the top left (rather than "Show all items", which is ticked by default).